# Find number of companies who are in the different region Linq Query

Tags: linq

How to I construct a linq query for finding the amount of companies in the different regions.

```
Region Class
-------------
int Id
string Name

Company Class
-------------
int Id
string Name
int RegionId

i.e 
Asia = 100,
Middle East = 200,
.. etc
```

Comment: We would need a lot more data in order to help.... Do you have a list of `Region`? Is it from a Database? Show us what you've tried, explain the issue you're facing, etc.

Comment: Its from a Database, Company has region Id so I want to get the number of companies per region

Comment: @dijam - Have you tried anything? it's quite simple linq

Comment: Yes I want to find number of companies per region meaning I need to query region and  companies at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the LINQ `GroupBy` method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx ).

Assuming you have a relationship between Regions and Companies, and that region names are unique, you could use something like the following (or read the docs to learn how else to use the Group By data):

```
Companies
.GroupBy(c => c.Region.Name)
.Select(g => new { 
       Region = g.Key, 
       CompanyCount = g.Count()
});
```